# How do you refresh a hibernate hsql.dat file?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I need to update my hsql.dat.script file that is created in the build.  I changed the java hibernate code and now there is a query in it that has a contradiction.  Is there a way to administer the database while my web app is running?

I am trying to add a table to this db.

I am using the timeTracking SampleApp for QBO.
https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/SampleApp-TimeTracking_Invoicing-Java

Answer (score 0):

In my case using the sample app, all you have to do is delete the database.  Always save first though.  You will lose the data.

The database should regenerate.  This is the angular Model View Whatever framework.